# Invalid syntax errror on SQLite execute command

Tags: python, json, sqlite

I've got the following python 3 code:

```
import sqlite3
import json

conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
c = conn.cursor()

types = json.load(open('marketTypes.json'))

for data in types['items']:
    c.execute('INSERT INTO marketTypes (id, name, href) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', 
            (data['id_str'], data['type']['name'], data['type']['href'])

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

The database has already been created with a marketTypes table and 3 fields; id, name and href.

The json file looks like so, the first two fields that is, it is quite a long file.

```
{'items': [{'id': 18,
        'id_str': '18',
        'marketGroup': {'href': 'https://crest-tq.eveonline.com/market/groups/516/',
                        'id': 516,
                        'id_str': '516'},
        'type': {'href': 'https://crest-tq.eveonline.com/types/18/',
                 'icon': {'href': 'http://imageserver.eveonline.com/Type/18_64.png'},
                 'id': 18,
                 'id_str': '18',
                 'name': 'Plagioclase'}},
       {'id': 19,
        'id_str': '19',
        'marketGroup': {'href': 'https://crest-tq.eveonline.com/market/groups/517/',
                        'id': 517,
                        'id_str': '517'},
        'type': {'href': 'https://crest-tq.eveonline.com/types/19/',
                 'icon': {'href': 'http://imageserver.eveonline.com/Type/19_64.png'},
                 'id': 19,
                 'id_str': '19',
                 'name': 'Spodumain'}},
```

When I run the python file I get:

```
File "sqlite.py", line 13
conn.commit()
   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas on how to solve the issue? I apologize if the title is not as specific/helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an unclosed parenthesis:

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO marketTypes (id, name, href) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', 
         ^  (data['id_str'], data['type']['name'], data['type']['href'])
```

In a simpler form, this is `c.execute(query, (data)`. Note that the parenthesis from `c.execute(` is not closed.

Instead, it should be:

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO marketTypes (id, name, href) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', 
            (data['id_str'], data['type']['name'], data['type']['href']))
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thank you.